# Solving $\lim_{x\to+\infty}{x^2(\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+2})-1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to solve the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to+\infty}{x^2(\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+2})-1)} $$

That is $\infty·0$, so I rewrite the expression as

$$ \lim_{x\to+\infty}{\frac{x^2}{\frac{1}{(\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+2})-1)}}}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}\ \ \ \text{ or }\ \ \lim_{x\to+\infty}{\frac{(\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+2})-1)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}}=\frac{0}{0} $$

so I can apply L'Hôpital's rule, but I did not succeed. Could you give me a hint?

(Limit solution is $-\pi^2/2$)

Comment: Taylor expand cos term and use uniform convergence of the Taylor's series on $(-\infty, \infty)$ to conclude that you may bring limit inside the sum. Everything should go to 0 except 2nd order term which should converge to your given answer.

Comment: How about using finite expansion?

Comment: @Fareed that sounds sufficient actually since all derivatives are bounded. Expanding to 4th order remainder is enough.

Comment: Maybe applying l'Hopital's rule twice on  $$ \lim_{x\to+\infty}{\frac{x^2}{\frac{1}{(\cos(\frac{\pi}{x+2})-1)}}}$$ will work too. But I am sorry I can't try it now I am a bit busy.

Comment: Don't worry @Fareed. I have checked that, in this case, Taylor is by far faster than applying many times L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** multiply by conjugate.
$$
x^2\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x+2}\right) - 1\right) = x^2\frac{-\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{x+2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x+2}\right)+1}
$$

Now:
$$
-\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{x+2}\right) \sim -\frac{\pi^2}{(x+2)^2}
$$

Using that in the original limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\frac{-\pi^2}{(x+2)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x+2}\right)+1} = -\frac{\pi^2}{2}
$$

Comment: It works, but I'm not convinced about $
-\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{x+2}\right) \sim -\frac{\pi^2}{(x+2)^2}
$. They both have the same limits when x tends to infinity, but is this change rigorous enough?

Comment: @Gibbs This is obtained by Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ as $x \to 0$. Since the original argument of $\sin$ is $\frac{\pi}{x+2}$ and it tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to infinity you may use first term of Taylor expansion.

Comment: Alright, so it seems Taylor is the easier way to solve the limit. Thanks!

Comment: @Gibbs glad I was able to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\dfrac{1}{x+2}\to 0^+$. Your limit becomes $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{t}-2\right)^2\left(\cos\pi t -1\right)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\dfrac{\cos\pi t-1}{t^2}-4\dfrac{\cos\pi t-1}{t}+4\cos\pi t -4\right)$$
Use L'Hopital's rule on the last two fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x+2=\pi/t$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\frac{\pi}{t}-2\right)(\cos t-1)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\cos t-1}{t^2}(\pi-2t)^2
$$
Can you compute
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\cos t-1}{t^2}
$$
and $\lim_{t\to0^+}(\pi-2t)^2$?